# sbt.IO zip how to preserve file permission

Tags: scala, sbt

I recently created sbt task to do the deployment stuff which include shell script. In the sbt task, I am using sbt-IO to zip the shell script file.

However, it looks like shell script inside zip file doesnt preserve the file permission. I know java.util.zip doesnt preserve permission as well but Gradle did, so what else solutions I have in sbt project if I still want to use sbt-io and I dont want to use command line zip plugin library like [sbt-native-package](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)

Comment: It seems IO.zip won't support to preserve permissions. https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/215